# One database connection in multiple thread inserting, updating data at the same time using transaction

Tags: java, mysql, multithreading

I am little bit confused, I know about transaction isolation.

Let's say I have 3 threads using one database connection at the same time and they are using transaction to insert and update data like that.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            Connection connection1 = null;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    connection1 = MysqlConnectionManager.getConnection();
                    connection1.setAutoCommit(false);
                    //execute some insert or update queries
                    connection1.commit();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally {
                    if(connection1 != null)
                        try {
                            connection1.setAutoCommit(true);
                        } catch (SQLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Let's say one of the threads has a query error. That means `connection1.commit();` will not execute and calls `connection1.setAutoCommit(true);` while the other threads did not call commit yet. will the others threads commit automatically the queries executed even if there was an error or is `connection1.setAutoCommit(true);` will not affect the connection in the others threads? Don't forget I'm using only one connection.

What would I do to able to work with these threads without having any probleme?

I have thinking about creating a new connection in each threads but, I'm scared about the Mysql database cries about multiple connections.

Comment: use datasources JNDI with you server. it might help you.

Comment: It will surely impact other threads if you are creating a direct connection and using same connection among multiple threads

Comment: What would I do to able to work with these threads without having any problem? I just read about datasources JNDI but it seems like to be a connection factory that returns the same connection or new connection. But I'm looking for a solution that I do not have to create new connections.